# proc и lambda, в чём разница?

Tags: ruby

Всем привет, читаю "Язык программирования Ruby" за авторством Флэнаган Д., Мацумото Ю.
Прочитал про lambda и proc и всё равно не могу их особо отличить и то, как с ними оперировать. Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, разъяснить разницу и навести какой-то практический пример. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Читаю эту же книгу, но до проков и лямбд не дочитал ещё.
Знаю, что между ними 2 разницы:

- лямбда чувствительна к кол-ву параметров. Тут она похожа на метод. Proc не чувствителен. Он похож на блок.

  Пример:

  ```
  x = Proc.new{|a, b| p "#{a} + #{b}" }
  x.call(11, 12)
  x.call(11) # Не выбросит исключение

  y = lambda{ |c, d| p "#{c} + #{d}" }
  y.call(13, 14)
  y.call(13) # Выбросит исключение
  ```
- Контекст выполнения. Proc выполняется в той области, где был определен. Лямбда - в той, где была вызвана.

  Пример:

  ```
  def one
    x = Proc.new{ p 'proc'; return }
    x.call # выполнится в контексте метода one
    p 'one'
  end

  one # return из прока выполнится в контексте метода, где был объявлен. 'one' - не будет выведено

  def two
    y = lambda{ p 'lambda'; return } # выполнится как метод, внутри метода two. Метод two продолжит выполнятся, и выведет 'two'
    y.call
    p 'two'
  end

  two # return из лямбды выполнится в контексте лямбды
  ```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!